# Android Studio Emulator Fonts Blurred

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

I have install flutter and android studio and setup as usual in new laptop running windows 11 pro. But when I start emulator its fonts are not clear, blurred. I tried switching emulated performance from hardware to software, but not works, is any one facing this issue.

My monitor display resolution  1366 * 768  Scale 100%
I used pixel  emulator with 1080* 1920 resolution
and Pixel 3a with 1080*2220 resolution

same problem exist with both emulators.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What physical resolution does your used monitor/screen has? What scale factor do you use in Windows for that monitor? My guess would be that the emulator is too large for your resolution+scale factor and thus the emulator is resized which doesn't work well.

Comment: My monitor display resolution  1366*768  Scale 100%
I used pixel  emulator with 1080* 1920 resolution
and Pixel 3a with 1080*2220 resolution

same problem exist with both emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think there would be a solution for that.
Because this problem is related to down scaling emulator window too much.

But you can do one of these:

1- create a new emulator and use a smaller screen size (around 720p). the downside is that you can not create emulator with Google play system images, as they need 1080p phone screen size. you can still use Google Apis images.

2- use a monitor with at least 1080p resolution.

3- use third party emulators like Memu. you can choose any screen resolution in these emulators, and they come with google play. also their performance is much better than Android studio native emulator.

4- use a physical Android phone.